# How to set default active element in SlickJS slider

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I have slick slider witch displays elements sorted by date and i want to preselect the last one (current month) to be default element.
For example if i have

[01 2015, 02 2015, 03 2015, 04 2015, 05 2015, 06 2015]

i want to display 06 2015 and when you swipe backwards to get older mounts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically what you want to do here is to set the initial slide to the current month. The solution is more or less straight forward. Executable example right below:

```js
$('.myslider').slick({
    initialSlide: ((new Date).getMonth())
});
```

```css
/* Slider */
.slick-slider
{
    position: relative;

    display: block;

    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;

    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
        touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list
{
    position: relative;

    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    display: block;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after
{
    display: table;

    content: '';
}
.slick-track:after
{
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide
{
    display: none;
    float: left;

    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
{
    float: right;
}
.slick-slide img
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img
{
    display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide
{
    display: block;

    height: auto;

    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

@charset 'UTF-8';
/* Slider */
.slick-loading .slick-list
{
    background: #fff url('./ajax-loader.gif') center center no-repeat;
}

/* Icons */
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

    src: url('./fonts/slick.eot');
    src: url('./fonts/slick.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('./fonts/slick.woff') format('woff'), url('./fonts/slick.ttf') format('truetype'), url('./fonts/slick.svg#slick') format('svg');
}
/* Arrows */
.slick-prev,
.slick-next
{
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;

    display: block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    padding: 0;

    cursor: pointer;

    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.slick-prev:hover,
.slick-prev:focus,
.slick-next:hover,
.slick-next:focus
{
    color: transparent;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.slick-prev:hover:before,
.slick-prev:focus:before,
.slick-next:hover:before,
.slick-next:focus:before
{
    opacity: 1;
}
.slick-prev.slick-disabled:before,
.slick-next.slick-disabled:before
{
    opacity: .25;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;

    opacity: .75;
    color: white;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.slick-prev
{
    left: -25px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-prev
{
    right: -25px;
    left: auto;
}
.slick-prev:before
{
    content: '←';
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-prev:before
{
    content: '→';
}

.slick-next
{
    right: -25px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-next
{
    right: auto;
    left: -25px;
}
.slick-next:before
{
    content: '→';
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-next:before
{
    content: '←';
}

/* Dots */
.slick-slider
{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.slick-dots
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -45px;

    display: block;

    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;

    list-style: none;

    text-align: center;
}
.slick-dots li
{
    position: relative;

    display: inline-block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0;

    cursor: pointer;
}
.slick-dots li button
{
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;

    display: block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;

    cursor: pointer;

    color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.slick-dots li button:hover,
.slick-dots li button:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-dots li button:hover:before,
.slick-dots li button:focus:before
{
    opacity: 1;
}
.slick-dots li button:before
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-size: 6px;
    line-height: 20px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;

    content: '•';
    text-align: center;

    opacity: .25;
    color: black;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.slick-dots li.slick-active button:before
{
    opacity: .75;
    color: black;
}


/* Custom */
.slide {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: tomato;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="myslider">
    <div class="slide">Slide 1A</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide 2B</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide 3C</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide 4D</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide 5E</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide 6F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i know about initial slide but seems like i have a older version of slick library and now when i update it, its fine.